# Isomorphism preserving operations

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

**Questions :** What are group modification processes ( group transformations ) which preserve the isomorphism property. One operation is **abelianization** of group does not preserve isomorphism. I mean to say if G and H are isomorphic iff G' and H' are also isomorphic. Where G' and H' are groups after applying group modification process.

Comment: What counts as a "modification"? Groups are rarely determined by smaller groups.

Comment: Extending groups to isomorphic supergroups seems equally unlikely to be helpful because you want an equivalent condition.

Comment: [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) are a nice example of something related (but note quite related enough to make this comment an answer!). [Group presentations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) are a way of viewing groups, and Tietze transformations are transformations applied to presentations (so they change the "view" of your group). Then two presentations $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ define isomorphic groups if and only if $\mathcal{Q}$ can be obtained from $\mathcal{P}$ via a sequence of Tietze transformations.